# How to join multiple databases on visual Studio c# Console App using Sql Command

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I have this command on my visual studio but I don't think I join my data tables in the correct way. How can I connect the datatables below ???

```
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT User.Id ,User.Name ,Checkpoint.Id ,Checkpoint.Coordinates ,Log.TimeStamp FROM " 
                    + "dbo.Users, dbo.Log, dbo.Checkpoints;" ,sourceConnection);
```

My tables:

```
  internal class Checkpoint
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Log
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public int CheckpointId { get; set; }

    }

    internal class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Coordinates { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: We need to see the tables to answer that. Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Well you are not joining tables at all, we need to see the content of those three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to do something like this. The sql below is a dummy assuming the keys that are used to join exist. But it should give you a basic idea of how to join your query since we dont have the content of those tables (what columns exist in each)

```
var sql = @"SELECT User.Id ,
                   User.Name ,
                   Checkpoint.Id ,
                   Checkpoint.Coordinates ,
                   Log.TimeStamp 
            FROM dbo.Users User
              INNER JOIN dbo.Log Log ON Log.UserId = User.Id
              INNER JOIN dbo.Checkpoints Checkpoint ON Checkpoint.Id = Log.CheckpointId ;"
```

You can find more details on sql joining here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

**Update:**
Just saw your edit. There is no way for you to join the user table unless the Coordinates makes any sense for you. For me it doesn't. You might want to add a reference to the UserId in the Log table as my SQL example above.

Comment: Well this is in Sql I want the queries in Visual studio

Comment: What do you mean in Visual studio? You mean that you have three lists, one for each type?

Comment: I have my tables in sql, and then I have my classes In visual studio. I have loaded my data in visual studio and now I want to manipulate with my data in visual studio. So I am using sql command to get all the data and manipulate with them

Comment: I get an exception error. Saying that there is an error near the keyword Checkpoint